# JTable column titles dont show up, instead they are 'A', 'B', 

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm new at using Java GUI and i'm trying to make a table with some scoring results of my soccerteam.

At first I was using the DefaultTableModel and I didnt have any problems with my columnnames. They showed up fine by using the JScrollpane. Then I wanted to try out to implement my own TableModel and since then i don't get to see my table column headers anymore. They show as 'A', 'B', ... , 'G', while I'm still using the ScrollPane.
I need this TableModel cause i'm planning on using the exact same structure for adding some other stuff too.

Can anyone help me please trying to solve this issue.

Thanks

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{  
    private String[] titles;  
    private Object[][] data;

    public MyTableModel(String [] t, Object [][] d){
        this.titles = t;
        this.data   = d;
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
        return data[row][col];
    }
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return titles.length;
    }
    public int getRowCount(){
        return data.length;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {  
            createAndShowGUI();  
        }  
    });  
}

public JPanel createContentPane(){
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

    String [] titles = {"Naam", "Doelpunten", "% Doelpunten", "Assists", "% Assists", "", "% Totaal"};
    Object [][] data = new Object[spelers.size()][titles.length];
    int counter = 0;
    spelers = getSpelersFromDB("all");
    for (Iterator<Speler> iter = spelers.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
        Speler temp = iter.next();
        data[counter][0] = temp.naam;
        data[counter][1] = temp.doelpunten;
        data[counter][2] = String.format("%3.1f %%", berekenPercentageDoelpunten(temp));
        data[counter][3] = temp.assists;
        data[counter][4] = String.format("%3.1f %%", berekenPercentageAssists(temp));
        data[counter][5] = "";
        data[counter][6] = String.format("%3.1f %%", berekenTotaalPercentage(temp));
        counter += 1;
    }

    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(titles, data));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.setOpaque(true);
    return mainPanel;
}

private static void createAndShowGUI(){
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

    Voetbal demo = new Voetbal();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());
    frame.setJMenuBar(demo.createJMenuBar());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for people who have started to investigate this issue, but i have found it out myself. In order to show the columnnames, all i had to do was implement the method getColumnName in my MyTableModel Class

Comment: No need for apologies, but you might as well mark Fido's answer as 'correct'.

Answer (score 8):

AbstractTableModel will always return 'A', 'B'.... etc as a column name (check the documentation), what you need to do is overwrite the getColumnName() method, with something like:

```
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return titles[column]
    }
```